# Comment traduire « declutter » en français?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

J'ai trouvé désengorger ou désencombrer, mais comme le terme sera utilisé dans un article web qui se veut inspirant, je suis à la recherche d'un mot plus poétique, ou du moins plus joli.

Comment: Maurice Leblanc utilise désencombrer dans [Arsène Lupin, gentleman-cambrioleur](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/32854/32854-h/32854-h.htm): *En quarante minutes, le salon fut «désencombré» selon l'expression d'Arsène*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je pense à *éclaircir* ou *épurer*. Moins poétique mais plus courant en français *ranger*, *faire le ménage* (souvent employé au figuré). *Désencombrer* reste à mon avis la plus fidèle traduction.

Comment: J'aime beaucoup épurer, qui en plus d'être clair est aussi un joli mot.

Answer (score 6):

Plutôt que chercher des négatifs, pourquoi pas des positifs : *assainir*, *purifier*, *nettoyer*, *simplifier*.

Plus longs : *faire le ménage*, *faire place nette*.

Un peu plus éloigné : *ouvrir*, *fluidifier*, *lisser*.

Sinon dans le moins poétique *décongestionner* peut marcher aussi.

Comment: C'est une bonne idée d'avoir opté pour un terme positif! Merci de vos suggestions. Avoir découvert ce site est un vrai bonheur!

Answer (score 3):

Suivant le niveau de langage et le contexte, il y aurait aussi :

- *araser*
- *aplanir*
- *dégager*
- *faire place nette*
- *débordéliser*

et sûrmenent plein d'autres, surtout si on commence à partir sur des néologismes...